# Generate random words with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

From a given string, how can I generate random words, with each word having different random lengths in python?. This is the code i have so far:

```
from random import shuffle, randint, choice
f = open("random_words.txt", 'w')
words = input("enter characters: ")
min_len = int(input("enter min lenght: "))
max_len = int(input("enter max lenght: "))
real_max_len = max_len + 1
ran_len = randint(min_len, max_len)
sent_len = int(input("enter amt of words to generate: "))

l_word = list(words)
word_len = randint(min_len, max_len)

for scat in range(sent_len):
    shuffle(l_word)
    sh_word = "".join(l_word)
    for times in range (ran_len):
        ran_word = choice(sh_word + " ")
        f.write(ran_word + "")
    #f.write(sh_word + " ")

f.close()
```

Comment: Can you describe how your code behaves, and how it differs from what you're looking for?

Comment: When you say words, do you mean dictionary words, or just a collection of characters, being a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overcomplicated the problem.  You can just use `shuffle` to rearrange the letters, then take the first `n` letters to create a new word, where `n` is a random number between you min and max length.

```
word_list = list(words)

for scat in range(sent_len):
    shuffle(word_list)
    new_word = ''.join(word_list[:randint(min_len, max_len)])
```

Comment: Thank you. Never thought of that